# Unable to Run MySQL

Tags: mysql-workbench

After installation I am unable to run MySQL Workbench 6.3 ce. Its getting below error. Its sucessfully installed but still unable to run it. I have .net framework 4.6 in my system.

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: BEX64
Application Name:   MySQLWorkbench.exe
Application Version:    6.3.5.0
Application Timestamp:  56226658
Fault Module Name:  db.mysql.grt.dll_unloaded
Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 562262cf
Exception Offset:   000007feed6f2e31
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Data: 0000000000000008
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID:  16393
Additional Information 1:   c0de
Additional Information 2:   c0dea3fec17049c654f2372d5d495c29
Additional Information 3:   b7d1
Additional Information 4:   b7d142854f9458f2a4104a086840c826

Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
 C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

[image]

Comment: How did you install MySQL Workbench? Best is to use the MSQL Windows installer which checks the prerequisites required to run the tool. You need the .NET 3.5 runtime + the Visual Studio C++ 2013 runtime installed on your box.

Comment: did you install this with administrator privileges  and then run it as administrator ?

Comment: I have .NET 4.6 Framework & The Visual Studio C++ 2013 runtime installed. Please suggest.

Comment: Its my personal PC. My user account is administrator.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows not installed properly then then its getting this type of error.

Comment: Could you give some more information? This is far too general to solve the problem.